# How to handle selectedItem on hirarchy grid ZK

Tags: mvvm, zk

I got a problem with hirarchy grid, i am following this [zk live demo](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid/hierarchy),so i am using grid for header data and listbox for detail data, but when i am using the selectedItem property in listbox detail the second row detail become selected too,[Here is my UI design](https://ibb.co/W3Xb3yC)
This is my code i am using mvvm

```
<grid  model="@load(vm.headers )">
            <columns>
                <column width="40px" />
                <column label="Nomor Part" sort="auto(name)" style="color:black"/>
                <column label="Description" sort="auto(averageHigh)" align="center" style="color:black"/>       
                <column label="Hotline" sort="auto(averageVolume)" align="center"   style="color:black"/>
            </columns>
            <template name="model" var="item" >
                <row>
<custom-attributes details="${item.details}" hotline="${item.hotline}" partNumber="${item.partNumber}"/>
                    <detail open="false" fulfill="onOpen">
                        <!--<include src="/widgets/grid/hierarchy/season.zul" details="${details}" hotline="${item.hotline}"/>-->
                        <include src="/widgets/grid/hierarchy/season.zul" details="@bind(item.details)" hotline="@bind(item.hotline)" partNumber="@bind(item.partNumber)"/>
                    </detail>
                    <label value="${item.partNumber}" />
                    <label value="${item.partDescription}"/>
                    <checkbox checked="@bind(item.hotline)" onCheck="@command('checkHotline',hotline=item.hotline)"></checkbox>
                </row>
            </template>
        </grid>
```

And here is my list detail code :

```
<vbox>
            <listbox  width="100%" height="300px" model="@load(details)" mold="paging" pageSize="5" 
                             emptyMessage="no data found" >
                            <listhead style = "text-align: center">
                                    <listheader label="Kode Dealer"/>
                                    <listheader label="Nama Dealer"/>
                                    <listheader label="Alamat"/>
                                    <listheader label="Jarak"/>
                                    <listheader label="Aksi"/>
                            </listhead>
                            <template name="model" var="dtl">
                            <listitem style = "text-align: center" >
                                    <listcell label="@bind(dtl.dealerCode)"/> 
                                    <listcell label="@bind(dtl.dealerName)"/>                                                                       
                                    <listcell label="@bind(dtl.address)"/>
                                    <listcell label="@bind(dtl.distance)"/>
                                    <listcell>
                                        <checkbox checked="@bind(dtl.selectedDealer)" oncheck="@command('onSelectDealer',partNumber)" visible="@load(not hotline)"/>
                                    </listcell>
                            </listitem>
                            </template>                             
                    </listbox>
                     <div align="right">   
                        <button label="Cancel" onClick="@command('onSelectDealer',partNumber=partNumber)"/>
                    </div>
</vbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide advice without seeing your code. I would pay careful attention to the row expander code (from the demo)

```
                <!-- use custom-attributes to store quarters and stock in row, 
                    so it can be accessed later when detail onOpen -->              
                <custom-attributes quarters="${each.quarters}" stock="${each}" />
                <detail open="false" fulfill="onOpen">
                    <include src="/widgets/grid/hierarchy/season.zul"
                        stock="${stock}" quarters="${quarters}" />
                </detail>
```

Comment: i've edited my question and add some code hope it make you easy to help me thanks.

Comment: You have set custom-attributes but you aren't using them. Try changing your `include` line to `<include src="/widgets/grid/hierarchy/season.zul" details="${details}" hotline="${hotline}" partNumber="${partNumber}"/>`